# After Handling AssemblyResolve Event Still getting Exception FileNotFound

Tags: c#, .net, assemblyresolve

I have handled the `AssemblyResolve`-event but I still get a `FileNotFoundException`. I have subscribed to the event in the type initializer and call the `Assembly.LoadFrom` method in the `Main`-method:

```
class Program
{
    static Program()
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve+=new ResolveEventHandler(DeployAssemblyHandler);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {      
        try
        {
            System.Reflection.Assembly asm=Assembly.LoadFrom("AxInterop.SHDocVw.dll");            
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
        }
    }

    public static System.Reflection.Assembly DeployAssemblyHandler(object sender,ResolveEventArgs args)
    {            
        Assembly asm = null;
        string asmName = new AssemblyName(args.Name).Name;

        string deployAssemblyDirPath = ""; // Common.AppUtil.InstallDir + AppUtil.DeployedAssemblyDir;

        string[] deployDirectories = Directory.GetDirectories(deployAssemblyDirPath);            

        foreach(string deploy in deployDirectories)
        {
            try
            {
                asm = Assembly.LoadFrom(deploy + "\\" + asmName);
                break;
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { }
        }                   
        return asm;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the file `AxInterop.SHDocVw.dll` in the `bin` directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the similar problem and ended with using a new AppDomain AND (**important!**) setting the [PrivateBinPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomainsetup.privatebinpath.aspx) property. The good thing about another AppDomain is that you can unload the assembly if you do not longer need it. The (my) sample code is:

```
  public class ProxyDomain : MarshalByRefObject
  {
      public bool TestAssembly(string assemblyPath)
      {
         Assembly testDLL = Assembly.LoadFile(assemblyPath);
         //do whatever you need 

         return true;
      }
   }

 AppDomainSetup ads = new AppDomainSetup();
 ads.PrivateBinPath = Path.GetDirectoryName("C:\\some.dll");
 AppDomain ad2 = AppDomain.CreateDomain("AD2", null, ads);
 ProxyDomain proxy = (ProxyDomain)ad2.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(typeof(ProxyDomain).Assembly.FullName, typeof(ProxyDomain).FullName);
 bool isTdll = proxy.TestAssembly("C:\\some.dll");
 AppDomain.Unload(ad2);
```

**EDIT:** based on your comment you are just looking for the wrong event handler. In your case you should use an [AppDomain.UnhandledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) Event, because  AssemblyResolve Event has different purpose.

Comment: my issue is not to load the assembly but i have to check wheter the assembly resolve event has been called on loadfrom failed scenario

Comment: let me explain my scenario i have to load an assembly from my current working directory but if it does not exist there loadfrom have to raise assembly resolve event and my handler will search it some where else ... ...

Comment: if the accepted answer solves your problem, than it's ok, otherwise I would try using AppDomain.UnhandledException. Using my code you don't even need your routine as the dll will always be found

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `AssemblyName.Name` property returns the name of the assembly **without the extension**. You'll need to add `".dll"` to the end of the path. (Warning: This will obviously break if the assembly's extension is not .dll)

Comment: it never hits that line of code that is the event has not been raised and the exception filenotfound is thrown at loadfrom line ...

Comment: @RoyaanKhan Are you using Load or LoadFrom? You should probably be using Load.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Assembly.Load` in the Main method instead of `Assembly.LoadFrom`.
`Assembly.LoadFrom` shouldn't even call your custom resolver.

Answer (score 0):

Add AxInterop.SHDocVw.dll  in bin folder it should work.